# Optimize Windows Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have about 28GB of Data-In for a little over 13.5 million rows stored in Windows Azure Table Storage.

6 Columns, all ints except 1 decimal and 1 datetime.
Partition Key is about 10 characters long.
RowKey is a guid.

This is for my sanity check--does this seem about right?

The Sql Database I migrated the data from has WAY more data and is only 4.9GB.

Is there a way to condense the size?  I don't suspect renaming properties will put a huge dent on this.

*Note this was only a sampling of data to estimate costs for the long haul.

Comment: maybe this is not the time to say this, but are you sure your using the appropriate kind of storage for your information? it seems that you got a fixed schema and other things that are better suited when served by a relational database...

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that this migration was just a test to measure what costs I could expect.  The schema is not fixed and the data is non-relational in nature.

Comment: @Leonardo - I disagree; Relational databases shine with relational data, but if data can be looked up directly by partition+row, Table Storage is a fantastic alternative without the bulk of SQL (and scales to 200TB, something no SQL db can achieve in Azure). In any case: there's absolutely no way to make that type of decision without detailed knowledge of how the data's being accessed.

Comment: When you say Data-In, do you mean incoming bandwidth or the size of the table? As @DavidMakogon mentioned, based on the information provided, the size can't be 28GB for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... something doesn't seem to add up right.

- Each property is a key/value pair, so include property names in your calculations.
- The data itself is probably around 75-100 bytes including property names averaging 10 characters apiece. The 4 ints equate to 16 bytes, the decimal (double?) 8 bytes, and the timestamp 8 bytes. So let's just round up to 100 bytes per entity.
- at 14 million entities you'd have 100*13.5 million, or about 1.35 GB.

Your numbers are approx. an order of magnitude larger (about 2,000 bytes per entity). Even accounting for bulk from serialization, I don't see how you're getting such a large size. Just curious: how did you compute the current table size? And... have you done multiple tests, resulting in more data from previous runs? Are you measuring just the table size, or the total storage used in the storage account? If the latter, there may be other tables (such as diagnostics) also consuming space.

Comment: I computed by hand and received your same estimate.  But when I viewed the Portal Summary I saw that Data Transfer In is 27GB.  I am on a free account and have been disabled for going over so I can not test any further (though I may change the account type in order to).

Comment: I did enable logging.  Does that count toward storage? Oh gawd, I bet it does.  I also used Cloud Storage Studio to migrate the data from a Sql Database. I don't know if that programs add some overhead into the storage.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming properties in the entities that are persisted should have some impact on the size.  Unfortunately, that'll be only for data saved in the future.  Existing data does not change just because you've renamed the properties